# Android - Wait for volley response for continue

Tags: java, android, geofire

I build an app, that it load markers in a map, the markers I get it for volley JSON file, but I need that first to load volley, and after continue executing the code, because the other way show me error with **latLng null**, this parameter is not loaded fast, and another method execute first and show me null.

My volley code for load markers

```
public  void getMarkers(){

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray saagTracker = response.getJSONArray("saagMRK");
                for (int i = 0; i < saagTracker.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = saagTracker.getJSONObject(i);

                    title = object.getString(TITLE);
                    snnipet = object.getString(SNNIP);
                    latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(object.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(object.getString(LNG)));
                    coor = coor + "|" + object.getString(LAT) + "," + object.getString(LNG);                        // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map

                    addMarker(latLng, title, snnipet);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ocurrio un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

`onCreate` it need latLng first for it to can load my `geofire` parameter

```
geoQuery = geofire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude),0.1f); // latLng it coming null
```

Comment: when do you call `getMarkers()` ?

Comment: before of geofire parameter, into onCreate

Comment: just before the `geofire.queryAtLocation()` call ?

Comment: yes before: 
`getMarkers();`
`geoQuery = geofire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude),0.1f);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would need to implement a call back for the volley response. A very simple way to do this would be the following.

Step 1: Create this interface

```
public interface VolleyCallBack {
    void onSuccess();
}
```

Step 2: change your `getMarkers()` method to this:

```
public  void getMarkers(final VolleyCallBack callBack){

requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        try {

            JSONArray saagTracker = response.getJSONArray("saagMRK");
            for (int i = 0; i < saagTracker.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = saagTracker.getJSONObject(i);

                title = object.getString(TITLE);
                snnipet = object.getString(SNNIP);
                latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(object.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(object.getString(LNG)));
                coor = coor + "|" + object.getString(LAT) + "," + object.getString(LNG);                        // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map

                addMarker(latLng, title, snnipet);

                callback.onSuccess();

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ocurrio un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Step 3: Call your `getMarkers()` method like this:

```
getMarkers(new VolleyCallBack() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    // this is where you will call the geofire, here you have the response from the volley.
                    geoQuery = geofire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude),0.1f);
                });
```

Comment: Very thnks for u help