# Android Async Task not Working as Expected

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am new to Android Development.
I am trying to load data from MySQL database through SplashScreen.
I am using Async Task to fetch the data.

Basically what the application is trying to do is:
Fetch Restaurant Tables and Food Categories from the Database
Show these tables as a grid in MainActivity.
OnClicking these tables another Activity will open which will show the list of Categories to order Food.

I am trying to fetch all the data and store them in static ArrayList before the main Activity starts.
This is my Splash Screen.

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        BackgroundConnection.handleSSLHandshake();

        new DineIn(this).execute();
    }
}
```

I don't want to fetch data from the database again and again so I stored data in a static arraylist to use it again.
Once the data for the DineIn class is fetched, I want to fetch Data for another Class (Category).

This is my DineIn class to fetch Data from the Database.

```
public class DineIn extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void > {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    Context context;

    public DineIn(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        new Category(context).execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, StaticFields.URL_TABLES,
                response -> {
                    try {
                        StaticFields.DINE_TABLES_LIST.clear();
                        DineInData dine ;
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            dine = new DineInData();
                            JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            dine.setTable(product.getString("TableName"));
                            dine.setTableID(product.getInt("TableID"));
                            StaticFields.DINE_TABLES_LIST.add(dine);
                            System.out.println(StaticFields.DINE_TABLES_LIST.get(i).getTable() + " Dine Tables");
                        }

                    } catch ( JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                },
                error -> {

                    error.printStackTrace();
                });
        //stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy( 50000, 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(stringRequest);
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am expecting that once this task is completed then **onPostExecute** method will be called which will run another **Async Task** to fetch Category data and store that in an ArrayList.

Once the Data is fetched, run the main Activity and provide the DineIn Data to Recyclarview Adapter.
Here is the Code for Category.

```
public class Category extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    Context context;
    
    public Category(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        System.out.println("Sub Category handler1");
        for(SubCategoryData data : StaticFields.SUB_CATEGORY_LIST){
            System.out.println("List Return " + data.getCategoryName());
        }
        for(DineInData data : StaticFields.DINE_TABLES_LIST){
            System.out.println("List Return " + data.getTable());
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)context).finish();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, StaticFields.URL_CATEGORY,
                response -> {
                    try {

                        SubCategoryData subData ;
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject rs = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            subData = new SubCategoryData();
                            subData.setSubCategoryID(       rs.getInt(StaticFields.SUB_ID));
                            subData.setCategoryID(          rs.getInt("Category"));
                            subData.setCategoryName(        rs.getString(StaticFields.CATEGORY_NAME));
                            subData.setSubCategory(         rs.getString(StaticFields.SUB_NAME));
                            subData.setSubCatType(          rs.getString(StaticFields.SUB_TYPE));
                            subData.setSubCatRate(          rs.getDouble(StaticFields.SUB_SALE_RATE));
                            subData.setSubCatIngredientRate(rs.getDouble(StaticFields.SUB_ING_RATE));
                            subData.setSubCatPurchaseRate(  rs.getDouble(StaticFields.SUB_PURCHASE_RATE));
                            subData.setTaxable(             rs.getInt(StaticFields.SUB_TAXABLE));
                            subData.setAvailable(           rs.getInt(StaticFields.SUB_AVAILABLE));
                            //subData.setSubCategoryImage(    rs.optString(StaticFields.SUB_IMAGE));
                            StaticFields.SUB_CATEGORY_LIST.add(subData);
                            System.out.println(StaticFields.SUB_CATEGORY_LIST.get(i).getSubCategory() + " Sub Categoresi");

                        }
                        System.out.println("Sub Category handler");

                    } catch ( JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                },
                error -> {

                    error.printStackTrace();
                });
        //stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy( 50000, 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(stringRequest);
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am expecting that once the data is fetched and stored in the ArrayList, **onPostExecute**
method will be called which would finish the SplashScreen Activity and run the MainActivity.

But The results are completely opposite
Here is the output

```
08/05 18:04:59: Launching 'app' on Nexus 6P API 29.
Install successfully finished in 2 s 515 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.shahab.restaurantms/com.shahab.restaurantms.SplashScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 17619 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:551): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7272 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c143,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.shahab.restaurantms
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/ab.restaurantm: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ab.restaurantm: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd6053190, tid 17647
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd601a120: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd601a120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xd600f1c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd60532d0, tid 17647
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ffff6000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd601a120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xd600f1c0)
W/ab.restaurantm: Verification of java.io.InputStream com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream() took 176.729ms
I/ab.restaurantm: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 5729(1653KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 82% free, 1325KB/7469KB, paused 13.823ms total 1.002s
I/System.out: Sub Category handler1
W/ab.restaurantm: Verification of void com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setChannelIdPrivateKey(java.security.PrivateKey) took 874.592ms
I/System.out: T1 Dine Tables
    T2 Dine Tables
    T3 Dine Tables
    T4 Dine Tables
    T5 Dine Tables
    T6 Dine Tables
    T7 Dine Tables
    T8 Dine Tables
    T9 Dine Tables
    T10 Dine Tables
I/ab.restaurantm: Background concurrent copying GC freed 3555(458KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(3984KB) LOS objects, 43% free, 7865KB/13MB, paused 2.110ms total 147.113ms
I/System.out: Fajita Pizza Sub Categoresi
    Tikka Pizza Sub Categoresi
I/System.out: Supreme Pizza Sub Categoresi
    Crown Crust Sub Categoresi
I/System.out: Kabab Pizza Sub Categoresi
I/System.out: Veg Pizza Sub Categoresi
    Special Pizza Sub Categoresi
    Zinger Burger Sub Categoresi
    Beef Chanp Sub Categoresi
    Cheese Shawarma Sub Categoresi
I/System.out: Chicken Cheeze Sub Categoresi
    Beef Rice Sub Categoresi
    Biryani Sub Categoresi
    Apple Sub Categoresi
    Cocacola 500ml Sub Categoresi
    Cheese Paratha Sub Categoresi
    Sub Category handler


08/05 18:04:59: Launching 'app' on Nexus 6P API 29.
Install successfully finished in 2 s 515 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.shahab.restaurantms/com.shahab.restaurantms.SplashScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 17619 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:551): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7272 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c143,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.shahab.restaurantms
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/ab.restaurantm: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ab.restaurantm: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd6053190, tid 17647
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd601a120: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd601a120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xd600f1c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd60532d0, tid 17647
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ffff6000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd601a120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xd600f1c0)
W/ab.restaurantm: Verification of java.io.InputStream com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream() took 176.729ms
I/ab.restaurantm: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 5729(1653KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 82% free, 1325KB/7469KB, paused 13.823ms total 1.002s
I/System.out: **Sub Category handler1**
W/ab.restaurantm: Verification of void com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setChannelIdPrivateKey(java.security.PrivateKey) took 874.592ms
I/System.out: T1 Dine Tables
    T2 Dine Tables
    T3 Dine Tables
    T4 Dine Tables
    T5 Dine Tables
    T6 Dine Tables
    T7 Dine Tables
    T8 Dine Tables
    T9 Dine Tables
    T10 Dine Tables
I/ab.restaurantm: Background concurrent copying GC freed 3555(458KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(3984KB) LOS objects, 43% free, 7865KB/13MB, paused 2.110ms total 147.113ms
I/System.out: Fajita Pizza Sub Categoresi
    Tikka Pizza Sub Categoresi
I/System.out: Supreme Pizza Sub Categoresi
    Crown Crust Sub Categoresi
I/System.out: Kabab Pizza Sub Categoresi
I/System.out: Veg Pizza Sub Categoresi
    Special Pizza Sub Categoresi
    Zinger Burger Sub Categoresi
    Beef Chanp Sub Categoresi
    Cheese Shawarma Sub Categoresi
I/System.out: Chicken Cheeze Sub Categoresi
    Beef Rice Sub Categoresi
    Biryani Sub Categoresi
    Apple Sub Categoresi
    Cocacola 500ml Sub Categoresi
    Cheese Paratha Sub Categoresi
    Sub Category handler
```

Note that **Sub Category handler1** print statements is in the **onPostExecute** method of **Category** class and it is being printing first.
According to my expectections it should run at the last but it is executed first.
Then the Tables and Categories are being printed.
Due to this my **MainActivity** recyclarview sometimes shows tables and sometimes does not.

Please leave some suggestions that how should I perform this task.
Suggest me the right way to do this.
should I store data in static ArrayLists or fetch data from database again and again.
I tried running the Async Tasks Independently but same results.
I tried calling methods like this in splash screen but same results:

```
new DineIn(this).execute();
new Category(context).execute();
  System.out.println("Sub Category handler1");
            for(SubCategoryData data : StaticFields.SUB_CATEGORY_LIST){
                System.out.println("List Return " + data.getCategoryName());
            }
            for(DineInData data : StaticFields.DINE_TABLES_LIST){
                System.out.println("List Return " + data.getTable());
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Comment: Async task is deprecated. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask You should consider changing to Java.Util.Concurrent: https://www.baeldung.com/java-util-concurrent

Comment: You may be seeing a race condition on the write to the log file and not in the order of execution of the AsyncTasks but that is just a guess. Anyway, AsyncTask is deprecated because of real issues with it. Your code suppressing lint's static field leak check is just one example of problems. I would entertain moving away from AsyncTask using Thread or Executor. There is much information only about how to do work with background tasks that don't involve AsyncTask.

Comment: I tried using   ExecutorService and Handler from java.util.concurrent but the program doesn't waits for the data to be fetched. Is there a way that I could know that all HTTP requests are done and data is fetched successfully?

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor) regarding serialization of tasks. You could just execute your logic one after another in a single thread. Do you really need separate tasks? I think just one will do.

Comment: Thanks Guys! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342841/android-wait-for-volley-response-for-continue
this did my job

Comment: So, your background thread was generating its own background task without coordinating with your AsyncTask. That does explain what you are seeing.